# JavaFX: How to get number of rows of table view that are showing in virtual flow

Tags: java, javafx, row, tableview

I want to get number of rows for current virtual flow of table view
For Example, i have a table view of 1000 rows and table view shows only 50 rows for each page, how to get this "50" if the table view was responsive and can be 
re-sized .

Summery, i want keep my table view rows shows correctly, no row that half of it was hidden and another visible

please help me, and thanks in advance

This is an examples of problem:

```
            package application;

            import javafx.application.Application;
            import javafx.scene.Scene;
            import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
            import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
            import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
            import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
            import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
            import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
            import javafx.stage.Stage;


            public class Main extends Application {
                @Override
                public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
                    try {

                        //This is table view that will view model information
                        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();

                        //First name column to view first name attribute of person model
                        TableColumn<Person, String> firstName = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
                        firstName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));

                        //Last name column to view first name attribute of person model
                        TableColumn<Person, String> lastName = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
                        lastName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));

                        //Add this columns to table view
                        table.getColumns().add(firstName);
                        table.getColumns().add(lastName);

                        //Set dummy list of person to table view
                        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                            table.getItems().add(new Person("First Name" + i, "Last Name" + i));
                        }

                        //create TextField and bind what i want to its text property
                        //And what i want is : Number of rows that show on table virtual flow, by other words 
                        //that number of rows that is visible to me now according to table height
                        TextField box = new TextField();
                        // ????????????????? 
                        // ?????????????????

                        //Add table and box to border pane
                        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
                        root.setCenter(table);
                        root.setBottom(box);

                        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
                        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                        primaryStage.show();

                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                //This is model class
                public class Person{
                    private String firstName;
                    private String lastName;

                    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
                        super();
                        this.firstName = firstName;
                        this.lastName = lastName;
                    }
                    public String getFirstName() {
                        return firstName;
                    }
                    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
                        this.firstName = firstName;
                    }
                    public String getLastName() {
                        return lastName;
                    }
                    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
                        this.lastName = lastName;
                    }
                }

                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    launch(args);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Lea Tano for yours interest , i post some example , and thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To get the current number of visible rows you can include the following and call getNumberOfVisibleRows():

```
  private int getNumberOfVisibleRows()
  {
    VirtualFlow<?> vf = loadVirtualFlow();
    return vf.getLastVisibleCell().getIndex() - vf.getFirstVisibleCell().getIndex();
  }


  private VirtualFlow<?> loadVirtualFlow()
  {
    return (VirtualFlow<?>) ( (TableViewSkin<?>) table.getSkin() ).getChildren().get( 1 );
  }
```